# Is the ring smaller than normal in the Rocky movies?

Tags: realism, rocky-iv

I was watching Drago pummel Apollo Creed in Rocky IV and it seemed like the ring was smaller than a regulation ring. Normally, pro rings are 18x18 or 20x20, but the ring in Rocky IV seemed a lot smaller than that. Am I imagining things or did they use a small ring for cinematic purposes?

Comment: Did the Russian ring look smaller as well? Could be in-universe the Creed/Drago ring was smaller because it was an exhibition match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boxing rings vary from 16 to 24 feet per side, depending on the fight level and what the promoter of the fight wants.  Amateur fights take place in rings 16 to 20 feet per side, and professional fights take place in rings 18 to 24 feet per side.  Given that it's an exhibition, it could be fought in any ring between 16 and 24 feet per side.  I can not find any specific information on the Rocky IV movie, but you have to figure that both Creed and Drago stand taller than 6 feet.  Put them in a smaller ring, say 16x16, and that ring is going to look tiny.

Seeing as the promoter of the fight between Creed and Drago was Rocky, who was also Creed's trainer, it would seem odd that he would choose a smaller ring which gives an advantage to the taller Drago and his extremely dangerous 1,800 PSI punch.  So, that part of the movie would probably be counter to a realistic match.

Sources:

- [Wikipedia article on Ivan Drago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Drago)
- [Article on boxing ring dimensions](http://boxing.isport.com/boxing-guides/boxing-dimensions)

Comment: Are you sure about that math? 16 square feet would be a ring that's 4 feet by 4 feet, a ring that's 16X16 would be 256 Square Feet. I'm guessing that you meant 16 - 25 feet to a side...

Comment: Yes.  Sorry, I had a Spinal Tap moment.  I can now see Midget Wrestling in my head...